# cURL variable empty

Tags: javascript, php

I am using charts.js and trying to load data from a `JSON` API using `cURL` to pass to the chart. So I am using a PHP variable to pass to JavaScript. I did a test in ajax and it worked, but wanting to use `cURL` I cannot figure out the issue.

I created an if statement that it will print out nothing on an empty variable and that's what it has been doing, so I believe the issue is with `cURL`.

```
<?php 

$url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?currency=btc";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($curl);

if(!empty($data)) {
   $data = $btc;
} else {
    print ("nothing");
}
curl_close($curl);


?>

<body>
      <canvas id="myChart" width="250px" height="250px"></canvas>
 <script>
     jsonData=<?php echo $btc ?>;
     var jsonLabels=[];
     var jsonValues=[];
     for(x in jsonData['bpi']){
         jsonLabels.push(x);
         jsonValues.push(jsonData['bpi'][x]);
     }
```

Comment: Where is `$btc` defined?  Maybe you wanted `$btc = $data;` Also `var_dump($data);`

Comment: $btc is defined if its not empty. I just wrote the statement to see where the error was. I tried var_dump and its returning false.

Comment: What does curl_getinfo() return after you've executed your request but before you close the connection?

Comment: Do you really have a newline between `Accept:` and `application/json`, or is that a copying error?

Comment: @ReddHerring it returns nothing.

Comment: @Barmar copy/paste error on SO.

Comment: It really looks like you just have the assignment backwards, it should be `$btc = $data;`.

Comment: Are you sure you have `curl` enabled? When I try your code on my machine it works (after flipping the assignment), but when I try it on ideone.com I get `nothing`. I guess they block `curl`.

Comment: Change `print ("nothing");` to ` print ("nothing " . curl_error($curl));` so you see the reason why `curl` failed. On ideone.com it says "Could not resolve host: api.coindesk.com".

Comment: @Barmar Seems like its a ssl error, as my error when I did that was "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Comment: Try using `http:` instead of `https:`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: @Barmar removing the 's' corrected the issue. Thanks

Comment: it would probably be better if you fixed your certificate, as there may be other sites that require SSL.

Comment: @barmar yes I will, but at the moment this is hosted on a local server. When it goes live I will correct the ssl.